# Fullscreen background video aspect ratio on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have the following code to set a video as fullscreen background. It gets the browser dimensions and set the aspect ratio, so there should not be any black bars. Instead, either the top/bottom or sides overflow while still keeping the video centred.
The problem I have is if the the browser is resized. It kind of works, but I have a feeling that if the resize happens to fast, the script does not keep up, resulting in a white space along one of the edges.

Code below, jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/RobertCS/r50ktjoh/2/

```html
<div class="bgvideo">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/75542539?background=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1&badge=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bgvideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bgvideo iframe {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```js
function videoIframe() {
    //Get the browser dimensions and calculate aspect ratio
    var browswerWidth = $(window).width();
    var browswerHeight = $(window).height();
    var aspectRatio = browswerHeight / browswerWidth;

    if (aspectRatio < 0.5625) {
        //Video too tall for viewport.
        //Set the video width to the browser width
        //Set height according to aspect ratio.
        //Finally, offset top/bottom to keep video centred.

        var newHeight = 0.5625 * browswerWidth;
        $('.bgvideo iframe').css({
            'width': browswerWidth + 'px'
        });
        $('.bgvideo iframe').css({
            'height': newHeight + 'px'
        });
        $('.bgvideo iframe').css({
            'bottom': -((newHeight - browswerHeight) / 2) + 'px'
        });
    } else {

        //Video too wide for viewport.
        //Set the video height to the browser height
        //Set width according to aspect ratio.
        //Finally, offset left/right to keep video centred.

        var newWidth = browswerHeight / 0.5625;
        $('.bgvideo iframe').css({
            'width': newWidth + 'px'
        });
        $('.bgvideo iframe').css({
            'height': browswerHeight + 'px'
        });
        $('.bgvideo iframe').css({
            'left': -((newWidth - browswerWidth) / 2) + 'px'
        });
    };
};
$(window).resize(videoIframe);
$(document).ready(videoIframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it with a setTime function.

```
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    videoIframe();
  }, 250);
});
```